# Local Notifications on Android using Cordova 12

Tags: cordova, notifications, cordova-plugins

I have an app that is developed with Cordova and was using the Katzer's cordova-plugin-local-notification plugin.
When I upgraded it to Cordova 12 (to be able to target the sdk needed to publish the app to the Play Store) I was not able to build an apk anymore.
So after browsing for options read about some forks that could work, so I removed that version of the plugin and tried with cordova-plugin-local-notification-12 and @moodlehq/cordova-plugin-local-notification. But the issue, is that even I am now able to build the apk, the notifications are just not firing, no errors triggered when calling the commands to trigger the notification, but they just won't come up.
This happens with 2 devices with Android 12. I tried the same apk in an Android 9 Device and it works correctly.
Anyone having the same issue?

Comment: Did you find any better solutions so far?
cordova-plugin-local-notification does still seem to have 2.5-3k weekly downloads.
https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=cordova-plugin-local-notifications

cordova-plugin-local-notification-12 only has 350 weekly downloads.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-local-notification-12

@moodlehq/cordova-plugin-local-notification got 550 weekly downloads.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@moodlehq/cordova-plugin-local-notification

btw. does firebase not include local notifications? What is the main reason against firebase? Battery usage?

Answer (score 2):

Similar problem here - one thing I noticed immediately is that Android 12/13 does not give notification permission by default, and the plugin hasPermission()/requestPermission() does not generate a request to change the permissions as it did in the past.

The workaround (so far) was to use hasPermission() to detect if notifications are off and then prompt the user to go into Android settings and give the app permissions.

Once the permissions were on I was able to get Android 12/13 to show basic notifications.  Android 13 requires an additional call to setDummyNotifications() which I put near the top of my app.

However the Android 14 beta is another mess as it blocks the setExact() alarm notifications by default and they tell apps to "fail gracefully" so Android 14 requires a substantial rewrite to handle all cases.
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/changes/schedule-exact-alarms

Answer (score -1):

I think the way to go is to:

1. Migrate from Cordova to **Capacitor**:
   https://capacitorjs.com/docs/cordova/migrating-from-cordova-to-capacitor
2. Use the Capacitor specific **local-notification plugin** (38k downloads on 05.03.2024):
   https://www.npmjs.com/package/@capacitor/local-notifications

I will try this. :)

PS. Cordova seems to be replaced by Capacitor anyways - see **NPM-charts**:
https://npmcharts.com/compare/@capacitor/core,cordova